# Excel 2003: VBA Syntax causes problems in Excel 2010 - Alternatives?

Tags: vba, excel

I've got an old VBA-script (Office 2003) to fix which fails in Office 2010.
The problem seems to be caused by the syntax used to reference sheets and cells.

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
    "=EP!Z1S2:Z1S" & Mid(Str(Schritte + 2), 2)

    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
       .Values = "=EP!Z3S2:Z3S" & Mid(Str(Schritte + 2), 2)
       .Name = "=EP!Z3S1"
    End With
```

Is there an alternative to using "=Sheet!CellRange"?
Or can the problem be solved by changing some configuration in Office / Excel?

Comment: How does it fail? Any error messages?

Comment: What value is held by *Schritte*?

Comment: Yep. A VBA error message appears saying: "Runtime - Error 1004, Application- or object defined Error"  ... ?:-| ...  and the script stops.

Comment: Those cell references appear to be non-EN-US xlR1C1 style. What language pack is the 2010 under and what language pack was the 2003 under?

Comment: @Jeeped: It's an Integer asked via an input box. For example: 11 => "=EP!Z3S2:Z3S13". I think that's alright. The stopping of the script (in Excel 2010) seems caused by the used syntax.

Comment: @Jeeped: In the system settings of my Windows 7 it's German. Don't know which settings they used for Windows XP. But all labels etc. are in German so I guess they used it only in an environment with German settings.

Comment: If *Schritte* is 11 then `Str(Schritte + 2)` is 13 and `Mid(Str(Schritte + 2), 2)` is 3. Why not just `Str(Schritte + 2)`?

Comment: Yep. Exactly the same what I thought. But I displayed the return value of Mid(Str(Schritte + 2), 2) via MsgBox and it's correct. I suppose that this asking the value via InputBox adds additional digits to the value. And this digits shall be removed.

Comment: By the way: "Schritte" means "Steps"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the cell ranges as coded [Range objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) and/or [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx), possibly with the [Range.Resize property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

```
dim ws as worksheet
set ws = worksheets("EP")

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
  ws.range("Z1S2:Z1S" & Mid(Str(Schritte + 2), 2))

With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
   .Values = ws.cells(3, 2).resize(1, int(Mid(Str(Schritte + 2), 2)))    '=EP!Z3S2:Z3S" & Mid(Str(Schritte + 2), 2)
   .Name = ws.cells(3, 1)    '=EP!Z3S1
End With
```

When I created a chart using strictly strings describing the ranges, I received **Compile error: Type mismatch**. As soon as I wrapped the strings in `Range` or referenced them more directly with `.Cells` the problem disappeared and the chart generated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort and time. I really appreciate it.